# Determine whether a service was invoked in the past, or currently - for an installed app

Tags: android

I have an app with a service which is invoked for every SMS received by the app. The app itself has a very specific purpose, and SMS reception supports this purpose.

This SMS receiving service has been working solidly for a long time, and then on one specific day on one specific phone it stopped responding to SMSs, and continues to not respond.

I have that phone, and want to investigate with minimum disruption to it in its failed state. My fear is that an update may "fix" the problem!

The app internally logs the processing of SMS's, but only somewhat late after receiving them. There is no record in the internal logs of the the receipt of any SMS's since it first failed.

My best approach to investigating this problem is to determine whether the service was invoked on the day that it started to fail, and to be able to send it an SMS now and tell whether the service is invoked - without uninstalling or updating the apk.

The service is declared in the manifest with

```
<receiver android:name="myapp.services.SmsReceiver" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And the service is implemented as:

```
public class SmsReceiverService extends IntentService {

    public SmsReceiverService() {
        super("SmsReceiverService");
        // etc...
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "SmsReceiverService.onHandleIntent");
        // etc...
    }
    // etc...
}
```

How to detect if the service was or is invoked, for the installed apk?

Comment: You should see signs of your app in system messages in LogCat. This is particularly true if your process is not running, as there will be logging messages showing that. I haven't paid attention recently to see if `startService()` is logged specifically, as your process starting simply means that your receiver is receiving the broadcast.

Comment: Thankyou, @CommonsWare. I've just connected with LogCat (in the Android Device Monitor) and I see the main activity being started when the app is invoked by the user, but no trace of the `SmsReceiverService` when I sent it an SMS. I tried it with another phone which is working, and did get a full trace of the `SmsReceiverService`, including `onHandleIntent`.

Comment: Perhaps a higher-priority receiver is intercepting the SMS message and consuming it.